# How to specify vertex normals for a non-contiguous shape/surface in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I am trying to create a cylinder with GL_TRIANGLES and would like for this to produce shadows similar to objects created with models like glutSolidSphere. I believe I have to approximate the vertex normals for the shadows to work as intended but I am unsure how to proceed. (The code is more convoluted than it needs to be because of a university assignment.)

```
void drawTeaCup(void) {
    GLfloat matAmbient[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0 };
    GLfloat matDiffuse[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0 };
    GLfloat matSpecular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat matShininess[] = { 128.0 };
    glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, matAmbient );
    glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, matDiffuse );
    glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, matSpecular );
    glMaterialfv( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, matShininess );

    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, spotsTexObj );

    glDisable( GL_CULL_FACE );  // Disable back-face culling.

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(0.5, -0.3, TABLETOP_Z);
    drawCupVertices();
    glPopMatrix();

    glEnable( GL_CULL_FACE );  // Enable back-face culling.
}

void drawCupVertices()
{
    drawCylinderFan(0.35, 0.33, 0.36, 0.36); // Lid side
    drawDisc(0.36, 0.35); // Lid top
    drawCylinderFan(0.35, 0.2, 0.35, 0.25); // Top half of cup
    drawCylinderFan(0.2, 0, 0.25, 0.15); // Bottom half of cup
}

void drawDisc(double size, double height)
{
    std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 19> circle = getCircleTemplate();
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    for (std::array<double, 2> pt: circle) {
        double vertex[] = {pt[0] * size, pt[1] * size, height};
        glVertex3dv(vertex);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void drawCylinderFan(double high, double low, double highFrac, double lowFrac)
{
    std::array<std::array<double, 3>, 38> fan = getCylinderFan(high, low, highFrac, lowFrac);
    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    for (int i = fan.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::array<double, 3> pt = fan[i];
        double vertex[] = {pt[0], pt[1], pt[2]};
        glVertex3dv(vertex);
    }
    glEnd();
}

std::array<std::array<double, 3>, 38> getCylinderFan(double high, double low, double highFrac, double lowFrac)
{
    std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 19> circle = getCircleTemplate();
    std::array<std::array<double, 3>, 38> fan;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 38; i++) {
        if (i % 2) {
            fan[i] = { circle[i / 2][0] * lowFrac, circle[i / 2][1] * lowFrac, low };
        } else {
            fan[i] = { circle[i / 2][0] * highFrac, circle[i / 2][1] * highFrac, high };
        }
    }

    return fan;
}


std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 19> getCircleTemplate( void )
{
    static bool firstTime = true;
    int NUM_OF_SIDES = 18;
    static std::array<std::array<double, 2>, 19> unitDiscVertex;

    if ( firstTime )
    {
        // Pre-compute and store the vertices' positions of a unit-radius disc.
        firstTime = false;
        
        double theta = 0;
        double deltaTheta = (2 * PI / NUM_OF_SIDES);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_SIDES + 1; i++) {
            double nextX = cos(theta);
            double nextY = sin(theta);

            unitDiscVertex[i][0] = nextX;
            unitDiscVertex[i][1] = nextY;
            
            theta += deltaTheta;
        }

    }

    return unitDiscVertex;
}
```

[rendered screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMiTI.png)

I expected the cup with the lid here to cast shadows and reflections similar to the teapot and sphere on the table but it does not produce shadows at all.

Comment: Actually, none of the objects cast a shadow. However, you must specify the normal vector with [`glNormal`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glNormal.xml) (before [`glVertex`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml)) for the light model.

Comment: I see, I think I miscommunicated what I wanted to say. 

There are dark and light parts of the objects based on lighting. What you mention is what I thought I have to do as well, but my main problem is how would I calculate the normals for each vertex? Wouldn't they depend on the surface, which is just a bunch of different triangles? (Thanks so much for helping, even though the question was mis-phrased)